# DisplayForModel vs globalization

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, localization, globalization, asp.net-mvc-4

We are developing a website that should work in Portuguese and English!
For this we create the following architecture:

- Each class (Product, Service, Contact ..) has a field for pt-br and one for en-us. Here's an example:  http://chopapp.com/#1u9no3qw
- For the View to be displayed in correct language, the approach we use:
  [image: Solution]

### Remover.cshtml and Remover.us-en.cshtml

**There is no difference between the views!**

```
@using Resources
@using Dicionario = Semep.Recursos.Admin.Pagina.Remover
@model PaginaViewModel

@section css {
    @Script.StylesForms()
    <link href="~/Areas/Admin/Content/controller/paginas/remover.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <legend>@Dicionario.DesejaRemoverEstaPagina</legend>
    <fieldset>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, Strings.VerifiqueOsErrosAbaixo)
        @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </fieldset>

    <div class="buttons">
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancelar", "Index", "Solucoes")
        <input type="submit" value="SIM" />
    </div>
}
```

### DisplayTemplates\PaginaViewModel.cshtml

Displays the fields pt-br!

```
@model PaginaViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.ID)

<div class="display-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Link)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Link)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Nome)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Nome)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Texto)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Texto)
</div>
```

### DisplayTemplates\PaginaViewModel.en-us.cshtml

Displays the fields en-us!

```
@model PaginaViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.ID)

<div class="display-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Link)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Link)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.NomeEn)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.NomeEn)
</div>

<div class="display-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.TextoEn)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.TextoEn)
</div>
```

### Question

However, the data come only in "pt-br".
**How to work with DisplayTemplates and globalization in asp.net mvc?**

### Notes

I know this is not the best way to structure the data to work with globalization.
But the whole system is so, and **I have** to maintain this standard!